# How to Hiding Seconds Word Chars [PHP]

Tags: php, string

**If string has more than one word**

Example String:
AAAAAA BBBBB CCCCCCC

Output:
AAAAAA BB*** CCCC***

---

**If string has one word do nothing**

Example String:
AAAAAA

Output:
AAAAAA

---

I need to hide every last 3 chars of words if string has more than two word. I tried str_replace but I can't make it. Thanks for help

Comment: The idea at SO is you have a go at writing the code to fulfill your requirements. Then if you get an error or it does not do quite what you expected, you ask for help. Note: Help comes after you have at least made some effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, this could work for you.

```
<?php

$input = "AAAA B";

$words = explode(" ", $input);
for($i = 1; $i < count($words); $i++) {
    $words[$i] = substr($words[$i], 0, -3) . "***";
}
$output = implode(" ", $words);
echo $output;
?>
```

Keep in mind, though, if your words have less then 3 letters, they will be replaced to `***`.

Comment: @user1318741 glad to help :)